# Amazon Lightsail running ASP.NET Core web application - Unable to access website from browser

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I'm having trouble getting my ASP.NET Core MVC web application deployed on Amazon's Lightsail hosting.

I've followed [this](https://medium.com/@daniel.sagita/using-aws-lightsail-for-asp-net-core-920c69be7ff3) article on *Using Amazon Lightsail for ASP.NET Core* to get my aspnetcore 2.1 application build into a service and *nginx* forwarding any accesses on the site from port 80 to port 5000.

[image: Service Status]

My Lightsail instance is running perfectly fine:
[image: Lightsail Status]

From the SSH terminal, if I do a `wget http://localhost`, it returns an error saying there is no certificate. I have to force it with `wget http://localhost --no-check-certificate`, which then returns the index.html file for the webpage.

When going to the Static IP for my Lightsail instance on Chrome, however, nothing comes up on the webpage, saying **"The site can't be reached"**.

If I had to guess what the issue is, it would be something about the certificate. I've searched around for solutions to that but found nothing of help.

---

**What am I missing to get this application to run on the Lightsail Static IP so users can visit my website?**

Comment: Certificate should not be an issue unless you have provided instructions to use ssl in  nginx config. Since you have not done that it should be something else. Check if both nginx and .net services are enabled and running[`systemctl status <service-name>`]. Run `netstat -ntlp` to see if services are running on desired ports.

Comment: Check if you are able to access at least nginx from the external IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you open up the port on the lightsail firewall?

From your detail page for your instance click on networking and ensure you've added port 80

Also, try removing nginx and just accessing the application via port 5000 (after opening it up in the firewall).